# Ansible and nested variables in loops

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I there a way in Ansible to access variables in variables in a loop? For instance, configuring debconf to install a MySQL/MariaDB server needs two instructions like so:

```
- name: Define maria root password
  shell: echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password {{ mysqlRootPass }} | debconf-set-selections

- name: Define maria root password again
  shell: echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password {{ mysqlRootPass }} | debconf-set-selections
```

But that would be way more compact if I could do that:

```
- name: Define maria root password
  shell: {{ item }}
  with_items:
    - "{ echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password {{ mysqlRootPass }} | debconf-set-selections }"
    - "{ echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password {{ mysqlRootPass }} | debconf-set-selections }"
```

Obviously, that doesn't work.

so is there a way to make it work? Is there a better way of doing it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are there curly brackets `{}` in your `with_items`?

Comment: Actually that seems to work without curly brackets! I just had those  because I had some in a previous `with_items` with regex and replace vars inside. But it was stupid of me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{ }}` notation in Ansible comes from Jinja2 templates, it essentially directs Ansible to replace this with the contents of that variable.

`with_items` introduces the special variable `item`, which is the particular item of the current loop.

Therefore, you instruct the command module to execute `{ echo...`, namely whatever it is you have in `with_items`. You only need the command itself: `echo...`.

Reference: [Ansible docs: using variables and Jinja2](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables-about-jinja2)

Comment: Thank you for the enlightening explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my complete working MySQL role, that might help you.

**vars/main.yml**

```
mysql_root_pass: mypassword #MySQL Root Password
```

**tasks/main.yml**

```
---
 - name: Install the MySQL packages
   apt:
     name: "{{ item }}"
     state: installed
     update_cache: yes
   with_items:
     - mysql-server-5.6
     - mysql-client-5.6
     - python-mysqldb
     - libmysqlclient-dev

 - name: Update MySQL root password for all root accounts
   mysql_user:
     name: root
     host: "{{ item }}"
     password: "{{ mysql_root_pass }}"
     state: present
   with_items:
     - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
     - 127.0.0.1
     - ::1
     - localhost

 - name: Copy the root credentials as .my.cnf file
   template:
     src: root.cnf.j2
     dest: "~/.my.cnf"
     mode: 0600

 - name: Ensure Anonymous user(s) are not in the database
   mysql_user:
     name=''
     host: "{{ item }}"
     state: absent
   with_items:
     - localhost
     - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"

 - name: Remove the test database
   mysql_db:
     name: "test"
     state: absent
   notify:
     - Restart MySQL
```

**templates/root.cnf.j2**

```
[client]
user=root
password={{ mysql_root_pass }}
```

**handlers/main.yml**

```
---
 - name: Restart MySQL
   service:
     name: mysql
     state: restarted
```

**My site.yml look like this:**

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
    - mysql
```

If you are just looking to update the password of already configured MySQL:

In `vars/main.yml`

```
mysql_old_root_pass: olmysqldpassword
mysql_root_pass: newmysqlpassword
```

In `tasks/main.yml`

```
- name: Set root user password
  mysql_user:
    name: root
    host: "{{ item }}"
    password: "{{ mysql_root_pass }}"
    check_implicit_admin=yes
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_old_root_password }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
    - 127.0.0.1
    - ::1
    - localhost
```

Hope this will help you. If you need any help, please check this github [link](https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-roles/blob/master/LEMP/tasks/mysql.yml).

Comment: Actually the mysql `mysql_db` and `mysql_user` need an additional module on the server (at least on Ubuntu 14.04). That's why I don't use them.

Comment: It only needs "python-mysqldb" module.